# Misused limit for derivative definition?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

[image]

This is part of a solution to a problem. All you are given is that f is differentiable at a and the question asks to find the limit stated on the the left side of the last line. I don't understand how the last line of the solution is true when n goes to infinity. Isn't that only true if $|x-a|<\frac{1}{n}$? Shouldn't the limit be as $x$ approaches $a$?

Comment: it's the original limit going to infinity? at first glance, looks like a typo

Comment: yes. the question basically says to find the limit stated on the the left side of the last line.

Comment: yeah that would make sense to me only if $x \rightarrow a$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your observation is correct. The last line should say
$$
\lim_{x\to a}\frac{a^nf(x)-x^nf(a)}{x-a} = a^n\,f'(a) - f(a)\,n\,a^{n-1}.
$$
We are using the differentiability of $f$ and $x^n$ to get this result. Another way to convince yourself that it should be the limit as $x\to a$ is to see that the right hand side has $n$ in it, whereas after taking the limit as $n\to\infty$, the expression on the right should be independent of $n$.